# Do alter statements get rolled back if flyway migration fails?

Tags: flyway

Background

I am running a flyway migration against DB2 using the command line interface. I have done a number of tests and all works fine. I added in some commands to cause a failure.

Question

Can someone confirm if alter table, drop table or create table SHOULD be rolled back if the migration fails and the database supports DDL? When i test it it looks like an alter table add column statement was not rolled back after a failure in the same flyway script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i checked the flyway website and found a list of supported drivers and versions where DDL is supported. It seems like the version of DB2 we are using is below this threshold. Based on that i guess the execution of migrate script is not bound in a single transaction and that is why i am seeing some changes remaining that were applied before the script failure.